# Google Drive API does not return permissionIds when listing files

Tags: google-drive-api

The simplest attempt to list all files in a user's drive and get a list of the ones shared with others is not returning the list of `permissionIds` consistently. Sometimes I get it, and sometimes I don't.

Here is a very simple query I tried from the API explorer at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

[Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(id%2CpermissionIds)%22%7D):

```
corpora=user
fields=files(id,permissionIds)
```

Request as seen in debug logs: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user&fields=files%28id%2CpermissionIds%29`

[Response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files(id%2CpermissionIds)%22%7D) (trimmed the extra entries from the output for simplicity):

```json
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1Y_i8-TMfnhxhImlf2IsiJSO4aOqmAULz",
  }
}
```

Some of the files have the `permissionIds` not set, when it should be.

If I play around with the `pageSize` parameter I get differents sets of files that have the attribute set or not.

For example, I even tried doing this very simple query:  `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&corpora=user&fields=nextPageToken,files(id,permissionIds)&pageSize=1000` where I tried different values for `pageSize` of 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, and 1000. The following table shows the results I got for each query and the number of `permissionIds` (of course I also updated the `pageToken` as appropriate.

The following table shows the results and their number of `permissionIds`. For example the 0th to 39th results have identical `permissionIds`, but then result number 40 had 28 permissionIds for pageSize 10, 20, and 40, and did not have permissionIds set for pageSizes of 30, 50, 100, and 1000. I verified the `id` are all the same.

Even for `pageSize=100`, the first page of results is missing it, then I got it populated for 100 to 120, then it is missing again from 120 onwards (which is the second page of results for pageSize=100).

| [↓↓ `files` result index ↓↓] [⇉ pageSize ⇉] | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 | 50 | 100 | 1000 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40 | 28 | 28 | null | 28 | null | null | null |
| 41 | 10 | 10 | null | 10 | null | null | null |
| 42 | 7 | 7 | null | 7 | null | null | null |
| 43 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | null | null | null |
| 44 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | null | null | null |
| 45 | 11 | 11 | null | 11 | null | null | null |
| 46 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | null | null | null |
| 47 | 1 | 1 | null | 1 | null | null | null |
| 49 | 6 | 6 | null | 6 | null | null | null |
| 50 | 26 | 26 | null | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 51 | 26 | 26 | null | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 52 | 2 | 2 | null | 2 | 2 | null | null |
| 53 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 54 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 55 | 26 | 26 | null | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 56 | 26 | 26 | null | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 57 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 58 | 25 | 25 | null | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 63 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | 30 | null | null |
| 65 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 67 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 68 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 69 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 70 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 71 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | null | null |
| 72 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 73 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 74 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 75 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 76 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 77 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 78 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 79 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 80 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 81 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | null | null |
| 82 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 83 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 84 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 85 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 91 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 92 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | null | null |
| 93 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null |
| 100 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 101 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 102 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 103 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 104 | 26 | 26 | null | null | 26 | 26 | null |
| 105 | 26 | 26 | null | null | 26 | 26 | null |
| 106 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 110 | 26 | 26 | null | null | 26 | 26 | null |
| 111 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 112 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 114 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 115 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 116 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 117 | 25 | 25 | null | null | 25 | 25 | null |
| 120 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null | null |
| 121 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null | null |
| 122 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null | null |
| 123 | 25 | 25 | 25 | 25 | null | null | null |

I will accept a reasonable reliable way to get the permissionIds, hopefully without having to do a `get` on every single file.

Answer (score 0):

The [file.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) request has an optional parm called files which will force it to return back all of the response data.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

That being said the only permissions you are going to get back is the owners permission.

response

```
 "owners": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#user",
     "displayName": "xxxxx",
     "photoLink": "https://..../AOh14GhkDDDZulUhea-c-7_eeZFaG8zpfx6QWKOnTHwYJE8=s64",
     "me": false,
     "permissionId": "13642264623635",
     "emailAddress": "xxxx@gmail.com"
    }
   ],
```

To get the permissions on a file you should do a [permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list) and pass the file id

Assuming that the user making the request is the owner of the file they will be able to see who else has permissions on that file.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1x8-vD-XiXEEA5Spf3qp8x2wltablGF22Lpwup8VtxNY/permissions?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: But I *can* get the `permissionIds` as long as I put a search in the `q` parameter of the request.

Comment: Actually you dont need to i can permissionIds by just requesting fields=*